# Tax behaviour when I'm adding new item to basket

Tags: magento

I'm solving issue related to showing prices with TAX in basket. I have configured some tax rules for UK countrym which is 20%. In fronend I can see prices with tax. That's fine. But when I added a product to basket them it's displayed without tax amount, but it would as I enabled in backend.

My configuration is

1. TAX depends on delivery address
2. I specified default delivery address in backend, country = GB, region = *, postcode = *

I would expect: If I dont specify any delivery address then default delivery address would be used.

So I went depper I found that there are methods `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->collectTotals()` and `$address->collectTotals()` which operates with Country, Region and postcode. Their values are Country = GB, region is empty, postcode is empty. That's the reason why `Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation::getRate` returns 0 tax rate.

I can override this function and but there default delivery address configuration but I'm not sure whether I break anything or nor :)

**Is it standard behaviour or is it bug?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug.  I see you are  using the UK language pack so I'll answer using the terms from that.

Either you have configured something wrongly in the backend (have you set basket prices to display inclusive of tax in Config->Sales->VAT->Shopping Basket Display settings?) or your
theme has been set up badly and deliberately displays prices without tax in the cart even if you have set the config so they should be included.

Magento handles UK/EU inclusive tax setup really well, don't go down the rabbit hole of trying to alter the core for this.

Switch themes and see if that solves it. Your templates/checkout/cart.phtml file should contain a series of conditionals which checks the config settings and displays the prices with or without tax in the cart (or both).

Comment: I checked data in sales_flat_quote_item and there was record with zero tax. So I dont think so that happens because of themes. My setup is 1) prices includes tax; 2) display price with tax everywhere. I found that issue happens in method `Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation::getRateRequest` where shipping and billing addresses are passed into method with populated country GB (which is correct) but the rest is not populated and then it cannot find any tax rule. Maybe I have wrong tax rules setup but I'm not able to find out how would be rule set, for country = GB, region = empty, postcode empty?

Comment: @Jaro Billing and shipping addresses? Sorry I thought from the title that it was just in the basket. Have you set the origin address as the UK in configuration->Sales->Delivery Settings?

Comment: Yes, I did, but my configuration in System > Config > Tax is Tax Calculation Method Based On = Unit Price, and Tax Calculation Based On = Delivery Address. So origin address is not used in this case. I think System > Config > Tax > Default Tax Destination Calculation would be used, there I configured Default Country = UK, Default State = *, Default postcode = * And I created such tax rate rule in Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Zones & Rates. See my fix here https://gist.github.com/3849333 I updated `case 'shipping'` branch, so now it uses default values and it works.

Comment: OK, well glad you've got it working.  I have to say I've set up loads of UK Magento sites in every version from 1.3 onwards (shipping both internationally and domestically) and never had to do anything like that to get it working properly.

Comment: I have delivered some sites too. So it wonders me why it doesnt work for me, anyway it works now with this small tweak. I just hope that nothing is broken :)

Comment: I wasn't implying you were a newbie!! Sorry if it came across that way :) Glad you got it sorted Jaro.